# Limit the size of tmpfs with overlayroot

Tags: readonly, tmpfs, overlayfs

Recently I found out that it's possible to use overlayroot with tmpfs to create stateless readonly root.
However I couldn't find any info about limiting the size of tmpfs. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify the size of a `tmpfs` using the [`size` mount option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC_MOUNT%C2%A0OPTIONS), or the `nr_blocks` option. With `size`, you can specify the size in bytes (or kibibytes, or mebibytes, or gibybytes), or as a percentage of installed memory.

The size of a `tmpfs` can be changed on remount, after the initial setup, so with `overlayroot` you could reduce the size of the file system by remounting `/media/root-rw`.

Comment: Will I have to do it on every boot or can it be done once?

Comment: You’d have to do it at every boot. It *might* work if you add an entry to `/etc/fstab` with the relevant option (and specify `noauto` so that `overlayroot`’s `mount` works); alternatively, you could add the remount in a startup script.

Comment: This is not clear. Can you share more details?

Comment: @Zioalex could you be a little more specific? Which part of the answer needs more details?

Comment: Isn't clear how and how make the change permanent on reboot. I found a way to fix the size on run-time.